# Compile VLC failing on luac 32-bits needed

Tags: lua, vlc, libvlc, luac

Trying to build VLC using the build steps outlined in https://wiki.videolan.org/OSXCompile/ but am failing on luac needing to be 32 bit. Uninstalled lua and reinstalled a bunch, no option to specify a 32 bit install with lua. Am I doing something wrong?

```
kevinbook:vlc kevin$ cd build
kevinbook:build kevin$ ../extras/package/macosx/build.sh
+ ARCH=x86_64
+ MINIMAL_OSX_VERSION=10.7
++ xcrun --show-sdk-version
+ OSX_VERSION=10.11
++ xcode-select -print-path
+ SDKROOT=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.11.sdk
+ getopts hvrk:a: OPTION
+ shift 0
+ '[' x '!=' x ']'
+ out=/dev/stdout
+ '[' '' = yes ']'
+ info 'Building VLC for the Mac OS X'
+ local 'green=\033[1;32m'
+ local 'normal=\033[0m'
+ echo '[\033[1;32mbuild\033[0m] Building VLC for the Mac OS X'
[build] Building VLC for the Mac OS X
++ dirname ../extras/package/macosx/build.sh
+ spushd ../extras/package/macosx/../../..
+ pushd ../extras/package/macosx/../../..
++ pwd
+ vlcroot=/Users/kevin/vlc
+ spopd
+ popd
++ pwd
+ builddir=/Users/kevin/vlc/build
+ info 'Building in "/Users/kevin/vlc/build"'
+ local 'green=\033[1;32m'
+ local 'normal=\033[0m'
+ echo '[\033[1;32mbuild\033[0m] Building in "/Users/kevin/vlc/build"'
[build] Building in "/Users/kevin/vlc/build"
+ TRIPLET=x86_64-apple-darwin11
+ export 'CC=xcrun clang'
+ CC='xcrun clang'
+ export 'CXX=xcrun clang++'
+ CXX='xcrun clang++'
+ export 'OBJC=xcrun clang'
+ OBJC='xcrun clang'
+ export OSX_VERSION
+ export SDKROOT
+ export PATH=/Users/kevin/vlc/extras/tools/build/bin:/bin:/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/Users/kevin/vlc/contrib/x86_64-apple-darwin11/bin:/Users/kevin/vlc/extras/tools/build/bin:/Users/kevin/build/bin:/bin:/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/local/bin
+ PATH=/Users/kevin/vlc/extras/tools/build/bin:/bin:/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/Users/kevin/vlc/contrib/x86_64-apple-darwin11/bin:/Users/kevin/vlc/extras/tools/build/bin:/Users/kevin/build/bin:/bin:/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/local/bin
+ info 'Building building tools'
```

...

```
checking if linker supports -Bsymbolic...
checking __attribute__ ((aligned ())) support... 64
checking for __attribute__((packed))... yes
checking execinfo.h usability... yes
checking execinfo.h presence... yes
checking for execinfo.h... yes
checking for backtrace... yes
checking if xcrun clang -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.11.sdk -mmacosx-version-min=10.7 groks MMX intrinsics... yes
checking if xcrun clang -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.11.sdk -mmacosx-version-min=10.7 groks MMX inline assembly... yes
checking if xcrun clang -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.11.sdk -mmacosx-version-min=10.7 groks MMX EXT inline assembly... yes
checking if xcrun clang -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.11.sdk -mmacosx-version-min=10.7 groks SSE2 intrinsics... yes
checking if xcrun clang -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.11.sdk -mmacosx-version-min=10.7 groks SSE inline assembly... yes
checking if xcrun clang -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.11.sdk -mmacosx-version-min=10.7 groks SSE2 inline assembly... yes
checking if xcrun clang -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.11.sdk -mmacosx-version-min=10.7 groks SSE3 inline assembly... yes
checking if xcrun clang -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.11.sdk -mmacosx-version-min=10.7 groks SSSE3 inline assembly... yes
checking if xcrun clang -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.11.sdk -mmacosx-version-min=10.7 groks SSE4.1 inline assembly... yes
checking if xcrun clang -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.11.sdk -mmacosx-version-min=10.7 groks SSE4.2 inline assembly... yes
checking if xcrun clang -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.11.sdk -mmacosx-version-min=10.7 groks SSE4A inline assembly... yes
checking if xcrun clang -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.11.sdk -mmacosx-version-min=10.7 groks 3D Now! inline assembly... yes
checking for LUA... no
configure: WARNING: No package 'lua5.2' found, trying lua 5.1 instead
checking for LUA... no
configure: WARNING: No package 'lua5.1' found, trying lua >= 5.1 instead
checking for LUA... yes
checking for luac... luac
configure: error: You need 32-bits luac when using lua from contrib.
kevinbook:build kevin$
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have a similar problem for compiling vlc-android. I am using 64bit Arch system, and I could not find 32bit lua or 32bit lua runtime.

As a temporary workaround, I simply disabled lua

> ./configure --disable-lua

then run either make or compile

> make

or

> ./compile

I am still searching 32bit lua to install on my 64bit Arch, even though multilib is enabled in my pacman configuration